# Sensor data from iPhone to PC using Java app

Tags: java, string, user-interface, numbers, sensors

i've found an app for iPhone called "SensorLogger" that can log the data of most of iPhone's sensors and then send them via e-mail, but it also can broadcast it over the network using UDP packets, here is the code (Java) i use to receive that data :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, IOException {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5555, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
        byte[] buf = new byte[64];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        while (true) {
            socket.receive(packet);
            String data = new String(packet.getData());
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(data.split(",")));
        }
    }
}
```

it works perfectly, here is the output with the app on the iPhone running :

```
[1343331999601, 4, 0.0013, -0.0049, -0.00237]
[1343331999636, 4, -0.0024, 0.0049, -0.00477]
[1343331999670, 4, -0.0073, 0.0073, -0.00377]
[1343331999704, 4, -0.0036, 0.0024, -0.00247]
```

the 1st number is sort of a timestamp,  but i don't know what these numbers mean, it doesn't match with the date/time on the iPhone... the second number means what sensor is used, 1 is GPS position, 2 is compass, 3 is accelerometer, and 4 is gyroscope. The final numbers are the values from the sensor (defined by the 2nd number). Now, i wanted to do a small GUI app which would display all these values in a more user friendly way... but, this is the first time i program something in Java and i have no idea how to do that... can anyone please send a sample code so i can understand how to do it and repeat that for all of the values.

Thanks and have a nice day everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, i finally used this code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, IOException {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(5555, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
        byte[] buf = new byte[64];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        while (true) {
            socket.receive(packet);
            String data = new String(packet.getData());
            String[] dataParsed = data.split(",");
            float timestamp = Float.parseFloat(dataParsed[0]);
            float sensortype = Float.parseFloat(dataParsed[1]);
            float x = Float.parseFloat(dataParsed[2]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(dataParsed[3]);
            float z = Float.parseFloat(dataParsed[4]);
            String sensorname = new String();
            if (sensortype == 1) {
                sensorname = "GPS";
            }
            else if (sensortype == 2) {
                sensorname = "Magnetometer";
            }
            else if (sensortype == 3) {
                sensorname = "Accelerometer";
            }
            else if (sensortype == 4) {
                sensorname = "Gyroscope";
            }
            else if (true) {
                sensorname = "Unknown";
            }
            Date date = new Date();String line = ("Timestamp " + timestamp + ", local date " + date.toString() + ", sensor " + sensorname + ", x " + x + ", y " + y + ", z " + z);
            System.out.println(line);

        }
    }
}
```